# Module not found error when trying to deploy to gh pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my react app to github pages using the "gh-pages" dependency, first I got this problem when tried to install it:

```
Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
```

Eventually I installed it using `--legacy-peer-deps`, but when I tried to run the scripts to deploy i got this error

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' in '/Users/robertramirez/Documents/Coding projects/React projects/react-portfolio/node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
```

this is what my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "react-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "gsap-trial": "^3.10.2",
    "loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.5",
    "react-loaders": "^3.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.11",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

My app works fine when I run the script to create the local server but I also get the error when trying to build, maybe it has something to do with the react version that some dependencies use?

I'm adding more log information:

```
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! While resolving: react-leaflet@3.2.5
7:23:49 AM: Creating deploy upload records
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.x" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.18
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.1.18" from the root project
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   6 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-loaders, ...)
7:23:49 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   react-leaflet@"^3.2.5" from the root project
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-leaflet
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!     react-leaflet@"^3.2.5" from the root project
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this is

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I still get the same error, I think react-leaflet dependency might be the problem Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
node_modules/react-leaflet
react-leaflet@"^3.2.5" from the root project